# Problem with Google cloud SQL and Google pubsub together :Error A database name must be provided

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a rest application which which talks to google cloud sql and based on some data and I will sent data to pubsub topic. I have developing this two phase. Phase 1 getting data from cloudsql. I have successfully completed this and unit & integration test cases are working fine.
In second step i have included google pubsub dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

when added this I am getting following error

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A database name must be provided.`

As i understand after debugging once include the above dependency the code / testing code doesnt refer application.yml file

Note: In application YML file i use spring datasource uRL to connect to Cloud SQL database (which has db name, cloud sql socket factory, cloud instance and username / password) I dont use GCP specific properties for database. For refering google project id use google:cloud:gcp:     project-id:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by removing spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub dependency and added the google pubsub dependency.

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However still could not find out the root cause of error

Answer (score 0):

The cause is when `spring-cloud-gcp-starter` dependency (`pubsub` in this case) and `cloud-sql` are used together, it seems Spring will try to autoconfigure a Datasource object.

You can turn this off by specifying

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=false
```